# How to select a column in a table for searching values inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I just added the search bar in my Angular project with pipes.
At the moment the search bar works for all the elements in my table.

I would like to select a column in a dropdown or just with a checkbox and search the values just of that specific column.
How can I do it?

My columns are from an array of getColumns() in my service.

COMPONENT.HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-title">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="show-entries">
            <span>Show</span>
            <label>
              <select [(ngModel)]="pageSize">
                <option *ngFor="let maxPerPage of rowsOnPageSet"
                        (click)="maxElements(maxPerPage)">{{maxPerPage}}</option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <span>users</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h2 class="text-center">Users <b>Details</b></h2>
          <button *ngIf="metadata && metadata.addMD" (click)="addFunc(metadata)">{{metadata.addMD.label}}</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="search-box">
            <div class="input-group">

    -->MODIFY SOMETHING HERE
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchString" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="searchString">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" (click)="sortTable(col)">{{col}}
          <i *ngIf="col === columnSorted && !direction" class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
          <i *ngIf="col === columnSorted && direction" class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
        </th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users | paginate: {itemsPerPage: pageSize,
                                               currentPage: page,
                                               totalItems: users.length}  | filterAll: searchString">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{user[col]}}</td>
        <td>
          <button [ngClass]="getClassCondition(act.actionType)" *ngFor="let act of actions"
                  (click)="actionFunc(act, user)">{{act.label}}</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div align="center">
      <!--<div class="hint-text">Showing <b>{{totUsersPerPage}}</b> out of <b>{{users.length}}</b> entries</div>-->
      <ul align="center">
        <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"></pagination-controls>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </ul>
</div>
```

PIPE.TS

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterAll'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, searchText: any): any {
    if (!searchText) {
      return value;
    }
    return value.filter((data) => this.matchValue(data, searchText));
  }

  matchValue(data, value) {
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
      return new RegExp(value, 'gi').test(data[key]);
    }).some(result => result);
  }
}
```

Comment: And you want the table to filter them accordingly? Your question is not very clear, can you provide further details?

Comment: I need my search bar as you see it adding a dropdown.
Inside the dropdown I will have each one of my colums header.
They will have a check box so my search function will search just for the selected values. I have no idea how to do it and how to connect the checked box to the search method.

Comment: So assume you have a table with the following columns.
- First Name
- Last Name
- Middle Name

What you're saying is, you want your search bar to search for "Name", for example, and a drop down occurs with these three options, the user would select one or more, then they will hit "Search"

Then what happens? What's the expected result?

Comment: the table will show me the rows with that value present in that specific column.
At the moment I search in every data in every column  in my table.

Comment: Would you mind contacting me via christopheelkhoury@gmail.com so I can get a better understanding of what it is that you're trying to do, then I'll be able to provide a detailed answer?